# Using progress bars in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, progress-bar

I have a question about using progress bars, I searched for information on the subject and have found some examples of using bars as tkProgressBar tcltk library, does anyone know how to use them in complex codes with loops and comparators? 
Does anyone know how to use this type of bars? I put a code example to get an idea of the type of code to which I refer

```
 REGION_value<-as.character(GET_TEST_REGION(DF_TEST_file))
      SESSION_value<-as.character(GET_TEST_SESSION(DF_TEST_file))

      if(INIT_On_Time_value!="NULL" && END_On_Time_value!="NULL"){
          INIT_On_Time_value<-as.numeric(INIT_On_Time_value)
     }
      if(init_power_value!="NULL" && end_power_value!="NULL"){
          init_power_value<-as.numeric(init_power_value)
        }
  #parse id_device
      DF_device_value<-PARSE_status(URL_DEVICE_value)
      auxREST_REQ<-REST_GET_STOP_DEVICE(DF_device_value,URL_DEVICE_value)
      DF_inventory_items<-PARSE_INVENTORY_items(DF_device_value, URL_DEVICE_value)
    #-------------------------------------------#
      if(nrow(DF_inventory_items)>0){
        DF_epc_list<-GET_EPC_list(DF_inventory_items)
        DF_found_epc_tags<-FOUND_COMPARE_TAGS(DF_READ_EXTERNAL_LIST_EPC_TAGS, DF_epc_list)
       }
  if(init_power_value!="NULL" && end_power_value!="NULL"){

        if(init_power_value > end_power_value){
          init_power_value<-aux1
        }
           inventory_DF_List<-list()

            aux<-seq(init_power_value, end_power_value, 0.5)
            size_for<-length(aux)

          power_value_init=init_power_value
          for(i in size_for:1){
            DF_inventory_items_List<-PARSE_INVENTORY_items(DF_device_value, URL_DEVICE_value)
            if(nrow(DF_inventory_items_List)>0){
              DF_inventory_items_List<-subset(DF_inventory_items_List, select=(-tags))
              DF_inventory_items_List<-subset(DF_inventory_items_List, select=(-props)) 
            }
            inventory_DF_List[[i]]<-DF_inventory_items_List

            if(nrow(DF_inventory_items_List)>0){
              epc_list[[i]]<-GET_EPC_list(DF_inventory_items_List)
            else{
              found_epc_tags_list[[i]]<-data.frame()
            }
            power_value_init=power_value_init+0.5
          }
        DF_FOUND_EPC<-data.frame()
        for(i in length(found_epc_tags_list):1){
        DF_N_EPC[i,1]<-nrow(aux_epc)
        }
          colnames(DF_N_EPC)<-c("total_epc")
          colnames(DF_FOUND_EPC)<-c("found_epc")

          DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC<-cbind(df_power_values,DF_N_EPC, DF_FOUND_EPC)
          DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC_PER100<-cbind(df_power_values,DF_N_EPC, DF_FOUND_EPC_PER100)
          colnames(DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC)<-c("power_value","total_epc","found_epc")

          FINAL_MIN_VALUE_FOUND_ITEMS<- min(DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC[DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC[,3] == max(DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC[,3]),1])
          FINAL_MIN_VALUE_MAX_ITEMS <- min(DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC[DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC[,2] == max(DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC[,2]),1]) 
  }else{
    FINAL_MIN_VALUE_FOUND_ITEMS<-"Not executed"
    FINAL_MIN_VALUE_MAX_ITEMS<-"Not executed"}

  #HIST_EPC<-HIST_EPC_list(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter)
   HTML_OUTPUT_ITERATIONS(df_power_values, df_on_time_values, inventory_DF_List_on_time, inventory_DF_List)
  #PDF_FILE<-Pdf_print_inform(DF_inventory_items, DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter, DF_READ_EXTERNAL_LIST_EPC_TAGS, DF_epc_list )
```

Comment: Your example code is not really helpful since there is no explanation of what you're trying to do or where a progress bar would fit into this. What are you actually trying to do? And can you please create sample code that states explicitly what you're trying to measure the progress of?

Answer (score 2):

Not a `tkProgressBar`-related answer, but it seems that you may be searching for **some** computation progress indicator. When I am very lazy (and, gosh, how often am I), I use the following scheme:

```
niter <- 853 # number of iterations
for (i in seq_len(niter)) {
   Sys.sleep(0.1) # some fancy time-consuming operation
   cat(sprintf("\r%.2f%%", i/niter*100)) # print progress
}
cat("\n") # finalize
```

It just prints the status on the console. HTH

**EDIT**: Or, as @Thomas suggested, the `txtProgressBar` may come in handy:

```
niter <- 853
pb <- txtProgressBar(1, niter)
for(i in seq_len(niter)) {
   Sys.sleep(0.01)
   setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}
close(pb)
```

Comment: You should consider using the built-in [`txtProgressBar`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/txtProgressBar.html) function. Probably easier than writing something from scratch.

Comment: I could, indeed. Anyway, thanks, I made an edit to include your suggestion, if you don't mind.

Comment: Well I'm trying to do is use a progress bar to my code, which is similar to the example with multiple loops and comparators, where many functions are executed. I would use a bar like this: http://www.programmingr.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/winProgressBar.png with a function called winProgressBar, but am new to R and do not know how to use it in a complex code like mine

Comment: Did you study the Examples section in `?tkProgressBar`? It's a nice graphical progress bar. The example works after a call to `library(tcltk)`.

Comment: FYI: `winProgressBar` is a Windows-only analogue of `tkProgressBar` and `txtProgressBar` that has exactly the same interface, but a prettier (more Windows-consistent) appearance.

Comment: @gagolews I tried both of your code snippets.  Perhaps I am doing something wrong because on my computer neither seemed to provide an indication of progress.  The first loop simply printed `100.00%` after a long wait.  The second loop printed a series of `=` symbols with no indication of how long the string of `=` symbols would eventually be.

Comment: @MarkMiller: `txtProgressBar` defaults to fill the console width. And as for the first solution, I also observed that this (`\r` in fact) does not work on particular machines (Windows R Gui, AFAIR). In R Studio it's OK. It's an R-related issue..